# php, replace text with function call

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

in my custom made cms, i need to replace part of the text that is selected from database table, that contains:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
>   consectetur adipisicing elit
>   {Block}'myfunc', array(11,
>   'thumbnail', 'large', 18){/Block} sed
>   do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
>   et dolore magna aliqua

part of the text with {Block}, shoud be replaced with php function that will execute function myfunc, and pass parameters that contains mentioned array.

bigest problem for me is that i don't know how many {Block} i will have in text, and where they will be placed.

i know that i can simply "explode" text, and do some gymnastics, but i don't know if it is best way to it.

i know this is not simple one... if you can help me with it, please.

thank you in advance!

Comment: You should use preg_replace(), you can pass a modifier that makes it search for all '{block}{/block}' strings.

Comment: @user198003 & @Gerben Jacobs: do NOT use preg_replace. It's completely pointless for this kind of application. Any kind of string replacement is bad for complex string parsing like this. It will fail if block is part of text as a parameter, etc. If your building a CMS system with this kind of templating, you'll need to parse each template just as a real language does. Look at the likes of modx. That'll give some starting ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know, everybody hates me, when I want to do everything with regex, but I like it :)

```
$text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit {Block}'myfunc', array(11,'thumbnail','large',18){/Block} sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna {Block}'myfunc', array(453,'thumbnai23l','small',6458){/Block} aliqua";
function myfunc($data) {
    return '<'.$data[0].'-'.$data[1].'-'.$data[2].'-'.$data[3].'>';
}
preg_match_all("/{Block}'([^,]*)', array\(([^\)]*)\){\/Block}/i", $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $text = str_replace($match[0],$match[1](explode(",", $match[2])), $text);
}
echo $text;
```

Just, be sure to seperate array values with same seperators, in my case its just comma, in your case, it was comma + space. Tune whatever you like.

And stuff like this, can be easely exploited, so, be sure to check if $match[1] is in your allowed functions list ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

> str_replace('{block}','<?php');
>   str_replace('{/block}','?>');